# Old VB project to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net

I'm being asked to re-write/modernize/update an old VB app. The fiels are all ".vb" but there is a .sln and a .vbproj file.  I try opening these in VS 2015 and it shows in Solution Explorer by name with (0 projects) and (unavailable) and "The project was unloaded"

Typically informative and helpful Microsoft text when all the tools are theirs. I digress.

How can I identify what this project is (VB 6?, VS 2010? Some flavor of .NET?).  Presume I know nothing please.

How can I bring this into VS 2015 and start updating this code?  I have a running version of the exe, it's a simple form app that saves some input from various controls to a file. It must be retrieving some data to populate the controls/drop-downs - there is a
*DataSources* subfolder containing *MyApplication.datasource* saying it was created by Visual Studio.Net which contains:

```
<GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="MyApplication" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
   <TypeInfo>WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication, My Project.Resources.Designer.vb, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</TypeInfo>
</GenericObjectDataSource>
```

I See nothing that identifies the source tool -
some miscellaneous files - I can provide some info if requested here...don't want to burden you with gibberish.

> ```
>  This code was generated by a tool.
>  Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1
> ```

I see what looks like an installer exe *Visual Basic 2010 Express.exe*. Is this perhaps a flavor of SQL Express?

Any help getting me started with this would be appreciated. I would think I should be able to get this moved forward to VS2015 as a VB project - it's not a very robust app.

Opening a Solution in VS 2015 and NOT getting an error, but seeing an empty project/solution.

---

**Update**:

Here's the top of the

*.sln file*:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00 
# Visual Studio 2010
```

*.vbproj file*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> 
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration> 
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>

                        ...

  <ItemGroup> 
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"> 
      <Visible>False</Visible> 
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName> 
      <Install>true</Install> 
    </BootstrapperPackage> 
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5"> 
      <Visible>False</Visible> 
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.10.0"> 
      <Visible>False</Visible> 
      <ProductName>SQL Server 2008 Express</ProductName> 
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage> 
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1"> 
      <Visible>False</Visible> 
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName> 
      <Install>true</Install> 
    </BootstrapperPackage> 
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5"> 
      <Visible>False</Visible> 
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>

                        ...
```

Well I'm electing to EDIT my post, per recommendations, but now it seems I'm at the end of my original post, so its doubtful anyone will see this.

The only snippets omitted from my vbproj file are those that identify the name of the app - for security reasons. It is a corporate app after all.
Those sections don't contain anything useful in my opinion....anything relevant I included in the comments.

I received absolutely no informative messages when opening this project/ (or solution) in VS 2015.  It seems happy, it shows in Solution Explorer by name with (0 projects) and (unavailable) and "The project was unloaded".  I just don't get this - this is a microsoft tool opening a project created in a microsoft tool..and they can't do any better than that?

As far as enabling other dot net versions, I don't have admin access, I'm on corp computers. I recognize this is a pain for everyone...esp me.

I just can't believe I can't get anything informative.

1/29/24 - second edit

So the only tool I'm able to install is VS 2024.
Upon loading the solution file, it informs me its incompatible and to open the Migration Report that will be displayed after clicking OK.  Of course, no Migration Report is made available, nor are the changes that will be made "automatically", made.  So why would anyone trust Microsoft dev tools?  This stuff never stops. I've been trying to trust them for 30 years and get the same endless BS.

This is the completely useless info they spew at me: (sensing a little angst here??)

Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
- , "C:\Users<userid>\dev<appname><appname>.vbproj"

Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
- , "C:\Users<userid>\dev<appname><appname>.sln"

1/29/234 - third update

Sorry, VS 2022, not 2024 installed.
btw - no log file was created in the solution folder, as was also promised.

1/30/24
"Did you not get any message about upgrading the project when you opened the solution file in VS 2015? Looks like this solution was created in VS 2010, and you should have been prompted to let VS 2015 upgrade the solution and project for you."   - No, that's what's so strange - it acts as if everything is normal, opens the project, yet simply shows it as (0 projects) and "Unavailable"

1/30/24 -
"Did you try asking VS2015 to reload the project via the Solution Explorer as I previously asked? "   - This option doesn't appear to be available in Solution Explorer.  fyi - the app solution appears open, just empty/unavailable.

Re" .NET 3.5 - I can work on getting my IT dept to install this, but its extremely difficult.  I will try.

1/31/24
Thanks TnTinMn - really appreciate the suggestion/help!

When I elect to Reload the project, it doesn't do anything.
Would like to paste an image here, but it really only shows the same info (the project file was unloaded).
I do not have any .suo files in the project folder.
There are some dataset files, and an app.config file which contains:

```
          <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>

and a connection string section which confirms its using SQL Express:
          <connectionStrings>
           <add name="AppName.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Integrated 
               Security=SSPI;"
              providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
           <add name="AppName.My.MySettings.MyAppNameConnectionString"
              connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx.cert.xxx.com;Initial 
              Catalog=MyAppName;Integrated Security=True"
              providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
       </connectionStrings>
```

IT seems awfully simple, not clear why VS wouldn't load this.  But thanks for your suggestion -

Comment: .sln and .vbproj files mean it's a .NET flavor of VB.  Both are text formats, so you may be able to learn something by reading them.  You may be able to try opening just the project file without the solution, in case there is something wrong with the solution file.

Comment: how does the folder look like. one solution is tp make a new project import all vb files and then **fix** all errors, warnings and messages. but it woud be better to start this with vs 2022

Comment: the project should thus allow being opening by using Visual Studio, and opening the .sln file. However, I would suggest you try vs2019. (or vs2022), but vs2019 is a better choice. In fact, you may well find that the project already been used/opened/developed with a later version then vs 2015 (after all, that is 9 years old now!!! And I thought that vs went from 2013 to 2017, and I not really sure there was a vs2015, so some confusing here. As for the dataset? That simple means they used the dataset designer. Think of the dataset designer as a "before" EF (Entity Framework). So, that's a ORM.

Comment: ah, yes there was a vs2015 -- I skipped that version and jumped from 2013 to 2017.

Comment: I recommend that you start by opening the _.sln_ and _.vbproj_ file using Notepad instead of Visual Studio. Also, if you haven't already done so, ensure that you make a copy of the entire project prior to making any modifications. In the _.sln_ file it will show which version of Visual Studio the project was created with. You may consider adding the contents of the _.sln_ file and _.vbproj_ to your post.

Comment: `...it shows in Solution Explorer by name with (0 projects) and (unavailable) and "The project was unloaded"` - Have you tried right clicking on the project name line (the one with **unavailable** next to it) in the Solution Explorer window and selecting "Reload Project"?

Comment: trying to include vbproj file:  length limitations make this useless though.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
.
.

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>

Comment: <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.10.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>SQL Server 2008 Express</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>

Comment: Apologies for the blob postings - no idea what's relevant here. 
Here's the top of the  .sln file:

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I only have VS 2015 installed on my dev server (corporate).  I don't have admin rights to install newer. As noted, it doesn't give any errors when loading these, just presents a completely empty project.

Comment: @SM: Please add the information to the end of your post by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77883130/edit), not in the comments. Also ensure that you include the entire _.vbproj_ file.

Comment: Did you not get any message about upgrading the project when you opened the solution file in VS 2015? Looks like this solution was created in VS 2010, and you should have been prompted to let VS 2015 upgrade the solution and project for you.

Comment: You may have to enable .NET Framework 3.5, in Windows. Open Control Panel => View by: Small Icons (upper-right corner) => Programs and Features => Turn Windows features on or off (upper-left) => .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0). However, it's necessary to see the entire _.vbproj_ file to know.

Comment: _I'm at the end of my original post, so its doubtful anyone will see this_: Anyone who is following your post receives a notification.

Comment: _As far as enabling other dot net versions, I don't have admin access, I'm on corp computers_: Then submit a support ticket to your IT department to have it enabled. I think that it's quite probable that this is why the project isn't opening in Visual Studio. If this isn't an option, then create a new project targeting _.NET Framework 4.8_, and open the _.vb_ files using something else, perhaps try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), etc...or even Notepad.

Comment: Did you try asking VS2015 to reload the project via the Solution Explorer as I previously asked?  Also, as a last resort, you can still download [Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you are seeing some like this in the Solution Explorer.

[image: Unloaded Project]

This is the view of an **unloaded project**. If you do not see the line with "Solution ... (0 projects)", go to the Tools Menu and select options. Then under the "Projects and Solutions - General Section", make sure that the "Always show Solution" box is checked.

[image: Always show solution]

At this point, Visual studio has read the solution file (.sln file) and the solution user options file (.suo file).  The user options file stores the information as to whether or not the project is to loaded.

You should be able to reload the project via the Solution Explorer by right clicking on the project and selecting the "Reload Project" option.

[image: Reload project gif]

If this does not work, you can use Window's File Explorer to delete the user options file (VS will recreate one). Depending one how many different versions of VS where used to edit the solution, there may be multiple options files in the folder.  If the image below, there are 2 suo files and a folder that contains option files for VS2015 and above.  These can be safely deleted.

[image: Multiple User Option Files]